# Acra not work in Release Version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, acra

for reporting my Application Crashes use Acra library via  `Android Studio Gradle Dependencies` in this form :

```
 dependencies {
      compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
  }
```

Now in `Bebug version` it work and return crash report goodly but after export `Release version` of application not work and return this error in logcat :

```
Not adding buildConfig to log. Class Not found : " + className + ". Please configure 'buildConfigClass' in your ACRA config
```

Then i use `acra-4-6-2.jar` file instead `dependencies` but not work still!

Too before saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157931/compilation-error-after-upgrading-from-acra-4-5-to-acra-4-6) but was not helpful fore me.

With thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are Proguardng your app on release but have not added the relevant ACRA classes to your Proguard config.

See https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/ProGuard

Comment: I have tried it before , but not solve my problem :|

Comment: @Saeid: Then you should un-accept this answer so it's not pinned to the top of the page.

Comment: @mhsmith you correct, I'm not sure why accepted this answer in that time!

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers actually provided the fix.

To fix this issue, assign your `BuildConfig.class` to the `buildConfigClass` field on your `ReportsCrashes` annotation declaration.

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    buildConfigClass = BuildConfig.class )
public class YourApplication extends Application { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using so called "dynamic" configuration you are probably having "empty" annotation like `@ReportsCrashes()`.

In that case it turns out that ACRA does not create proper default config. The solution is simple: just add some fake property there like:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "placeholder")
```

which you will later override in the dynamic config...